# Web-page redirection

Tags: apache, http, squid

I am trying to achieve the following:

when a user types "print" (or "http://print") in the address-bar of the browser :

I want the user to be re-directed to a page : www.abc.com/print/

How can one achieve this ? I tried to lookup some squid configurations  but was unable to find the same.

Thanks!

Edit : I do not understand the deal with down votes, this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: I'm assuming this is in your LAN? Or local machine?

Comment: be careful with this, because some browsers have restricted words that let you go to some configuration issue, inside the browser (as Firefox, for example, does).

Comment: Yes , its on the lan & the page i am looking to redirect is 3rd party URL on the net. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "types print"? You need to refine your question to explain it more fully. Generally speaking, a proxy server cannot change the behavior of the browser's print command.

Comment: By types - print , i mean types print in the address bar. I assumed that was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable a user on your LAN to type "print" in the address bar and be redirected to a given hostname, you'll have to supply a DNS record to that effect.  This is not accomplished on a web server, nor is it web development in any respect.

There are several methods to resolving a given hostname to a given IP or to another hostname.  One way is to edit the client hosts file, as described in another answer.  One could also, if you have a DNS server running within your LAN environment, add A records to this effect.

You must understand how hostname lookups work from a browser.  When you type something in the address bar, your browser uses your operating system to resolve the hostname to an IP address. Your operating system uses its hosts file, internet connection, and other mechanisms to accomplish this.  This process itself has several tiers and steps that are outside the scope of the browser and which cannot be influenced by the browser.  Nor will arbitrary web servers be consulted in this process.  Your aim is to inject something in this process that resolves the hostname "print" to the webserver of your choosing - THEN web development might come in to play.

See: http://www.quackit.com/how-websites-work/how-dns-works.cfm